# Unable to add extra field. Error ID 79 appeared X-Cart

Tags: php, sql, database, function, x-cart

I am currently using X-Cart to create an online shop. I am trying to create 'company' fields in address book. I had follow the [instructions](http://forum.x-cart.com/showthread.php?t=58364&page=2):
but I was shown an `Error ID 79`.

According to the [forum](http://forum.x-cart.com/showthread.php?t=46183), it is an error due to database but I had checked and make sure

I do have the required field.

I wasn't able to create thread in X-Cart Forum and I am not very sure the reason. All I know is I was shown a message:

> you do not have the permission

Hence, my only solution left is to search help here, very sorry about it.

Comment: I had found the reason why but unable to answer my own question until 8 hours later.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guessed I shouldn't just followed blindly. I followed the instruction in adding the following code to func.order.php but after removing it away, everything just work miraculously. Sorry to waste the space on this post.

```
$_fields = array_keys($default_address_book_fields);

    foreach (array('b_', 's_') as $p) {

        foreach ($_fields as $k) {
            if($k!='address_2') {

                $f = $p . $k;

                if (isset($userinfo[$f])) {
                    $insert_data[$f] = addslashes($userinfo[$f]);
                }
            }

        }

    }
```